# Cannot run phploc installed through composer

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php

Here is my composer.json file. It installs successfully:

```
{
    "name": "lorem-ipsum",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.0.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "0.5.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.5.3",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.9",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.4.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "1.4.0",
        "phploc/phploc": "1.7.4"
    }
}
```

But when I then run:

```
./vendor/bin/phploc
```

I get error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPLOC_TextUI_Command' not found in /home/richard/projects/lorem-ipsum/workspace/vendor/phploc/phploc/composer/bin/phploc on line 70
```

I think there is some autoloading problem. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed soon after the release in [this commit a few weeks ago](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc/commit/a6fbaeba83a809b53b1319ce69efb4cddde7a584) - I would suggest that you use dev-master instead of 1.7.4 until the next release.